# Where to get Apache modules' .so files

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I need to have the ".so files" for the following modules.  How do I get all these modules? I downloaded, extracted and configured `httpd-2.2.31`, but did not find all these files.

```
LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module libexec/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_default_module libexec/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module libexec/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module libexec/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_default_module libexec/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule file_cache_module libexec/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule cache_module libexec/mod_cache.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module libexec/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule mem_cache_module libexec/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule dbd_module libexec/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule bucketeer_module libexec/mod_bucketeer.so
LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/mod_filter.so
LoadModule substitute_module libexec/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module libexec/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule ldap_module libexec/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_forensic_module libexec/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule logio_module libexec/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module libexec/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule expires_module libexec/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/mod_headers.so
LoadModule ident_module libexec/mod_ident.so
LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module libexec/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule asis_module libexec/mod_asis.so
LoadModule info_module libexec/mod_info.so
#LoadModule suexec_module libexec/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule cgid_module libexec/mod_cgid.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module libexec/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the listed files under /usr/lib64/httpd/modules

Answer (score 0):

Most common modules should all be installed by default and located in /etc/apache2/mods-available/

You then need to enable or disable the one's you need. For example

```
sudo a2enmod auth_basic
sudo a2enmod mod_deflate
sudo a2enmod mod_cache
```

Then to disable any you don't need you disable them with

```
sudo a2dismod auth_basic
```

Make sure to check what modules are actually loaded first by running

```
sudo apache2ctl -M
```

Any modules not in /etc/apache2/mods-available/ can be installed by this example (this will install the spamhaus module ... just an example)

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-spamhaus
```

Also please don't go messing with any .so files or trying to edit them. Any module that has any sort of configuration options available will have both an .so and a .conf file. Those without a .conf file cannot be messed with.